# CSS positioning for close button in form

Tags: html, css

I've created a search form using bootstrap. I've also used jquery to generate a delete search button (x) when text is input, however, I am stuck trying to get it on the same line as the search form (ideally in the box to the right).
As you can see in the second picture, when "1" is entered into the form the button is generated below the search form. I have included my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Before entering text]
[image: After entering text]

```
<form id="PWFS">
  <label for="Label">Info</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs"<i class="fa   fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i></button>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group btn-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control search" id="search" placeholder="Workflow #">
        <span id="searchclear" class="searchclear fa fa-times"></span>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <button id="WFFsearch" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<br>
```

CSS

```
.searchclear {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: where do you want the close button to come?

Comment: or could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: please use a jsfiddle or snipper..

Comment: @Lal _"on the same line as the search form (ideally in the box to the right."_

Comment: if you could share the fiddle with the issue reproduced, we can help you..I think you have to use `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lal, Phil and adamdc78. I just had to change the position to absolute.